# Importing specific data from a .csv fle

Tags: excel, csv, vba

I have hit a brick wall with the final bit of code for the tool I am making for work. We gather dimensional data automatically into a csv file and it has a format that I cannot work out how to process. For example:

heading1,data1,heading2,data2,heading3,data3,heading1,data1,heading2,data2,heading3,data3 and so on.

There are no line breaks in the csv file and I cant work out how to pick and choose the data that I want to insert into specific cells in my template. I cannot provide the csv file or template due to the nature of the information. Can anyone provide any insight? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I am trying to end up with

heading1,data1,heading2,data2,heading3,data3

heading1,data1,heading2,data2,heading3,data3

heading1,data1,heading2,data2,heading3,data3

Although there is variable number of data points that I need to account for

Comment: **Edit your Post to show the desired result from your sample.**

Comment: If there are no line breaks or carriage returns at all, you could read the entire file into a string with `Line Input #`, convert to an array with `Split` (as long as there are no commas in the data apart from those used as delimiters) and then index into the array to extract the relevant fields. That's just guesswork though without a clearer picture of what you're trying to end up with

Comment: Are there any key words you could use in heading1 to delimit a Split?

Comment: good idea, the beginning of the next parts measurement data is consistent for all of the csv files, namely PART_NO . I will do further research into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do get the output that I was looking for:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' --- BROWSE FOR FILE --- '

Dim FileName As String

FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Comma Seperated Values Files (*.csv), *.csv")
If FileName = "False" Then
    MsgBox "No file selected"
    Exit Sub
End If

' --- READ FILE --- '

Open FileName For Input As #1

r = 0
Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, Data
    r = r + 1
Loop

Close #1

' --- EDIT FILE --- '

Data = Replace(Data, " ,", ",")

Data = Replace(Data, ", ", ",")

Data = Replace(Data, ",PART_NO", vbCrLf & "PART_NO")

' --- SAVE CHANGES TO FILE --- '

Open FileName For Output As #1

Print #1, Data

Close #1
```

This puts the .csv file in a format that excel can import into the correct rows instead of all of the data being in the same row.